# Access to VirtualHosts from the local network

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtual-host

I have a Ubuntu Server 18.04 over VirtualBox VM where I've installed Apache and Nginx for some testing. The VirtualServer example.com up and running on the local machine. That VM is configured with 2 network adapters, 1st one configured as Internal Network and 2nd one as NAT in order to have internet connection.

A second VM, Ubuntu 18.04 (Desktop) is configured with Internal Network only. This VM can reach the Ubuntu server via IP but is unable to resolve example.com

I'm wondering if there is a way to make it happen without configuring a DNS server on the Ubuntu Server VM. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi AtomicNation! You can write an entry in the /etc/hosts file with the format `IP example.com`. Regards

Comment: @AtomicNation Welcome on SuperUser... You can [edit] your post adding the IP of the internal network interface in order to (hope to) receive a (more) detailed answer useful for other people too... do not forget to upvote and accept the answer(s) you may found useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose the IP of the web server is 10.0.0.1.

Write a line in the `/etc/hosts` file of the second VM (The client):

```
10.0.0.1     example.com
```

And it will be able to resolve example.com as 10.0.0.1

**Note**: It can be a tab, a space of multiple spaces to separate the two arguments

**Note 2**: This is for testing purposes only, not for production environments

**Note 3**: As @Hastur states, for the specific case of example.com, this should not be of any inconvenience as it is [reserved](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved), but if it actually is another domain, use only for testing purposes!

Comment: Hi Jorge, neat answer. Ps> `example.com` is  one of the _[managed Reserved Domains](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved)_... so even in a production environment it shouldn't incur in serious problems... but it is  always better to say.

Comment: Applause! hahaha, Thanks for your comment @Hastur, I just assumed that example.com was actually an example for him!! I figured that it wasn't actually example.com. But I didn't know it was reserved for this, so thanks for enlightening me!

Comment: Well I seem to remember  that instead of `example.com` in the beginning it was proposed [another one](https://www.whois.com/whois/fuckyou.com)... but actually someone had already registered it in the real life... `;)` ps> name related to the disappoint often felt when you test something...

Comment: Amazing story!!

Comment: Unfortunately It is an urban myth... 
Just check the issue date of the RFC 2606 ([where](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#page-3) it is reserved `example.com`) --June 1999-- and the one of the registration of the other name on whois --Registered On: 1999-07-08-- but it was funny to listen...

Comment: Well Jorge, indeed it will work, but the idea here, was for the server to be able to serve several VirtualHosts, as the 2nd VM is able to reach the host via ip (it's for educative purpose). But anyway it seems a good alternative as just a little edit in the host file to check VH are working looks quicker and easier than creating DNS in the server for each domain. Thanks!

Comment: For education purposes should be fine, the thing is, don’t serve a hundred clients by editing hosts file, that is what DNS is for. Glad it helped! Cheers!